# Windows forms application using MongoDB (Visual Studio 2008 C#)

Tags: c#, windows, forms, mongodb

I have mongodb installed and running. I can create documents, i can get documents, is there an easier way to bind each control (textbox,drop down) to each record/field in mongo?

Comment: Easier as opposed to what? There's at least 3 different ways to do this. Context man, context! :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You need to create a custom class structure that will work as the data model. Once you load data to your model, you can bind your grid to that object.

What type of application is this - ASP.NET or MVC?